# Calculate stock from two transaction tables to a third one in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one for incoming shipments and one for outgoing. There are a lot of stock queries in various groupings and they need to be fast, so I'd like to create a third table summing the above two and run the queries on that. Is this possible using SQL only?

Simplified example:

```
Table: INCOMING
id  productid  amount_in
------------------------
1   6          100
2   5          300
3   6           50
4   2           10

Table: OUTGOING
id  productid  amount_out
-------------------------
1   5          10
2   5          20
3   6          30
```

Resulting table should contain the remaining stock:

```
Table: STOCK
productid  amount
---------------------
2          10
5          270   -- 300-10-20
6          120   -- 100+50-30
```

Comment: I appreciate that this is a simplified example, but in general you shouldn't store data that can be easily derived from other data. Also, do incoming and outgoing really need to be separate tables?

Comment: There are about 50 thousand records in each table and it currently takes over two seconds to run a query. I ran some tests and calculating the stock is about 70% of this time. And stock does not change between queries (single user app). Incoming and outgoing are created based on very different data, so using one table would mean lots of extra columns that are empty for either incoming or outgoing.

Comment: 100,000 rows is trivial for a properly indexed data set - but two tables is (possibly) fair enough given the column differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have grouped the two tables using UNION ALL, to preserve similar records, then used an INSERT INTO SELECT statement from the obtained table by inserting the product id and the SUM of the amount, multiply the amount_out by -1 to subtract it in sum.

```
INSERT INTO STOCK 
SELECT productid, SUM(amount)
FROM(
        SELECT productid , amount_in AS amount FROM INCOMING

        UNION ALL

        SELECT productid , amount_out * -1 AS amount FROM OUTGOING)
GROUP BY productid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT productid, in - out AS amount
FROM
((SELECT productid, SUM(amount_in) AS in
FROM INCOMING
GROUP BY productid) AS a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT productid, SUM(amount_out) AS out
FROM OUTGOING
GROUP BY productid) AS b
ON a.productid = b.productid)
```